# sending sms from javascript or html Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am from Android background recently started working on PhoneGap I am having a trouble sending sms so can anybody help me with the same

I mean sending sms from javascript or html.
rightnow I am using this code

```
var link="sms:55555555?body=hssssssss"
window.location.href=link
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What doesn't work with that ?

Comment: it takes me to the sendmessage screen but it doesnt attaches the message body to the code

Comment: Hmmm...that should work. I know for a fact that: <a href="sms:5125551234?body=The SMS message.">Send SMS</a> works just great.

Answer (score 1):

It should work perfectly on plain HTML as below.

```
    <a href="sms:2547203100?body=My SMS message.">Click to Send SMS</a>
```

However with plain Java Script

```
   var link="sms:55555555?body=hssssssss"
   window.location.href=link
```

It not working Hope this helps